# How to store current cursor position within a cadence workflow activity

Tags: cadence-workflow

Within a cadence workflow activity what is the best practice to store the current cursor position when iterating over many entities? This will allow the workflow to begin at the last cursor in the event of a failure.

What is the correct way to store the current cursor?
Should we periodically [continue as new](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/07_goclient/09_continueasnew) with the current cursor?

```
func createReports(ctx context.Context, arg1 string, arg2 int) error {
    cursor := ""
    for {
        result, err := someService.GetContracts(ctx, nil, cursor, 100)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        for _, c := range result.Contracts {
            err := aChildWorkflow.StartPipeline(ctx, arg1, arg2)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        if !result.HasMore {
            break
        }
        cursor = result.NextCursor
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question it turns out what I was looking for is already provided by the cadence go client in the form of the heartbeat functionality:

- GetHeartbeatDetails:  extract heartbeat details from last failed attempt. This is used in combination with retry policy.
- RecordHeartbeat: sends heartbeat for the currently executing activity

```
func createReports(ctx context.Context, arg1 string, arg2 int) error {
    cursor := ""
    if activity.HasHeartbeatDetails(ctx) {
        err := activity.GetHeartbeatDetails(ctx, &cursor)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    for {
        result, err := someService.GetContracts(ctx, nil, cursor, 100)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        for _, c := range result.Contracts {
            err := aChildWorkflow.StartPipeline(ctx, arg1, arg2)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        if !result.HasMore {
            break
        }
        cursor = result.NextCursor
        activity.RecordHeartbeat(ctx, cursor)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Nice that you discovered that. I think the confusion came from the "restart the workflow" phrase in the question.

Comment: Would you edit the original question to remove "there are two possible errors that can restart the workflow" phrase? The question is about the activity restart, but from that phrase it sounds like you are talking about workflow restarts.